# Record a video with preview generates bad quality

Tags: android, camera, record

I try to create an application allowing me to make video recordings. My problem is that when I use the preview of the camera, the recording is very poor of quality. And without the preview, the quality is perfect.

**Can anyone explain this result?**

To display the preview of the camera, I call this method : `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);`

**To better explain my problem, I make screenshots of the result :**

- In case A, I call the method `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);`
- In case B, I delete the method

NOTE: To download my project, click [HERE](https://mega.co.nz/#!ARQ11bAI!NzYnhdcfQ4a78A3dJ33roEV-E9BSgJs1gG92jP7vv3c).

[image: Result in picture]

Comment: I checked your code on Nexus 5 and Galaxy S 3 and it works ok, no "poor quality". what device with what Android version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (but using back camera). I was showing the preview from the camera, but when I started recording (after using setCamera), no matter what I tried, I either ended up with really poor quality, crashing or freezing.

I explained my solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098734/1135847